# Find the maximum of $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \sin \alpha_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n \cos \alpha_i}$ for $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \sin^2 \alpha_i=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inequality, maxima-minima

> Given that
> $$\sum_{i=1}^n \sin^2 \alpha_i=1$$
> and $0<\alpha_i<\frac{\pi}{2}, \forall i$, how to derive the maximum value of
> $$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \sin \alpha_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n \cos \alpha_i}.$$
> When does the maximum occur?

It is a problem from my brother in high school.
The problem I want to solve gives $n=2023$ in specific, but I guess this number does not matter.

Comment: The restriction of $0 < \alpha_i < \frac{\pi}{2}$ tells me that the trig functions are a red herring. With that restriction, we know $\cos \alpha_i = \sqrt{1 - \sin^2 \alpha_i}$. So this becomes a problem of bounding $\frac{\sum_i  x_i}{\sum_i \sqrt{1 - x_i^2}}$ where $\sum_i x_i^2 = 1$ and $0 < x_i < 1$. My guess: lagrange multipliers. Try that and see if you get anywhere. The reason you've been downvoted is because you asked a question but didn't make an attempt first.

Comment: I've tried for couple of hours actually. Lagrange multipliers is not preferred since it is a problem from my brother in high school. I wonder if there is any elementary method, so that it is easier for him to understand.

Comment: It certainly has the flavor of a contest math problem. Not my strong suit, but it might yield to the usual tricks if you know them: AM-GM, Jensen's inequality, etc.

Comment: Cauchy Schwarz actually seems like the way to go here. I'll let you know if I come up with anything.

Comment: Do they want *an* upper bound, or the least upper bound?

Comment: It says "find the maximum value of ...". It is not a proof question. In other words, they want the least upper bound, with the condition when equality is achieved.

Comment: @Wang The answer it's $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}}.$ Show me your attempts and I'll show my solution. Without showing your attempts this topic would be deleted and I don't want that my solution would be deleted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = \frac1{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j\neq i} x_j \le \frac1{n-1} \sqrt{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{\sum_{j\neq i} x_j^2}$$

Can you finish the proof?

Comment: What justifies the middle inequality? I'm sure it's a standard result, but I don't recognize it.

Comment: Ah, I see. It's Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: I actually tried a very similar proof technique, but maybe I went about it the wrong way. I was able to bound $\sum_i \sin\alpha_i$ above by $\sqrt{n}$ and bound $\sum_i \cos\alpha_i$ below by $n -1$ giving an upper bound of $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n-1}$. But the obvious choice of setting $\sin^2 \alpha_i = \frac{1}{n}$ for all $i$ results in $\frac{\sqrt{n-1}}{n-1}$, which doesn't quite saturate the bound (but, frustratingly, gets as close as you like as $n$ gets large).

Comment: Yes your approach is natural. You probably used CS for the first bound and use that $\cos(\alpha) \ge \cos^2(\alpha)$ for the second.

Comment: Exactly. Did I make a mistake, or do you have to do something more clever?

Comment: No you did not make any mistake. By the way do you think the hint in the answer is clear enough?

Comment: I worked through it and I see that it works (I would have thought for sure that my cosine bound would need to be improved, not my sine bound). But I have no idea where it comes from. How did you know that we needed to rewrite as a double sum like that? Is this a standard trick for working with trig sums?

Comment: So the main idea is the fact that I observe that the condition are permutation free which induce symmetry between $\alpha_i$. When you take the same value for all $\alpha_i$ it will appear the $n-1$ and it gives me the idea that I used.

Comment: Ah, I see. That makes sense. Still, I'm surprised that the cosine estimate suffices.